# VS Post-Build event creating file instead of copying folder contents

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event, post-build

There is a folder that gets brought in from a reference when I build and is created in my output directory, the path to it is "bin/debug/lib". For legacy purposes I need this folder to be copied to the following path "bin/lib".

I am using the following post-build event but it is creating a single "lib" file instead of copying the folder contents to a new folder called lib.

```
copy $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)lib $(ProjectDir)bin\lib
```

[image]

EDIT

I managed to fix this issue by running `MKDIR $(ProjectDir)bin\lib` before the post-build event

Comment: Try `copy $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)lib\*.* $(ProjectDir)bin\lib`

Comment: Unfortunately, this has the same result

Comment: I see your update. `xcopy` might do the folder creation automatically for you. `xcopy $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)lib\*.* $(ProjectDir)bin\lib\ /Y /E /I`    Although it might need quotes around the paths. https://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm